# trying to create an array of items but i get: cannot use object of type Entity as array

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine, api-platform.com, symfony5

Hello please i am new to php and symfony i need help!!
i am using api platform,
I have an invoiceLineItems field which is an array of invoiceLineItems entity and when  when setInvoiceLineItems is called  it expects the parameter to be an object instead of an ArrayCollection.

this is an example of my invoiceLineItems entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Bundle\Entity;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: InvoiceLineItemRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`invoiceLineItems`')]
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read:InvoiceLineItem']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write:InvoiceLineItem']],
    collectionOperations: [
        'get',
        'post'
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        'get',
        'put',
        'delete'
    ],
)]
class InvoiceLineItem
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'AUTO')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
    #[Groups(['read:InvoiceLineItems', 'read:Invoice'])]
    private ?int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING, length: 255, nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['read:InvoiceLineItem', 'write:InvoiceLineItem', 'read:Invoice'])]
    private string $description;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::STRING, length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['read:InvoiceLineItem', 'write:InvoiceLineItem', 'read:Invoice'])]
    private string $subDescription;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::FLOAT, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['read:InvoiceLineItem', 'write:InvoiceLineItem', 'read:Invoice'])]
    private string $price;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::FLOAT, length: 255, nullable: true)]
    #[Groups(['read:InvoiceLineItem', 'write:InvoiceLineItem', 'read:Invoice'])]
    private string $vatPercentage;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::FLOAT, length: 100, nullable: true,)]
    #[Groups(['read:InvoiceLineItem', 'write:InvoiceLineItem', 'read:Invoice'])]
    private string $vat;

    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::FLOAT, nullable: false)]
    #[Groups(['read:InvoiceLineItem', 'write:InvoiceLineItem', 'read:Invoice'])]
    private string $totalPrice;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(
        targetEntity: Invoice::class,
        inversedBy: 'invoice',
    )]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(
        nullable: false
    )]
    #[Groups(['read:InvoiceLineItem'])]
    private Invoice $invoice;


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    public function setDescription(string $description): self
    {
        $this->description = $description;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getSubDescription(): ?string
    {
        return $this->subDescription;
    }

    public function setSubDescription(string $subDescription): self
    {
        $this->subDescription = $subDescription;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getPrice(): ?float
    {
        return $this->price;
    }

    public function setPrice(float $price): self
    {
        $this->price = $price;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getVATPercentage(): ?float
    {
        return $this->vatPercentage;
    }

    public function setVATPercentage(float $vatPercentage): self
    {
        $this->vatPercentage = $vatPercentage;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getVat(): ?float
    {
        return $this->vat;
    }

    public function setVat(float $vat): self
    {
        $this->vat = $vat;
        return $this;
    }

    public function getTotalPrice(): ?float
    {
        return $this->totalPrice;
    }

    public function setTotalPrice(float $totalPrice): self
    {
        $this->totalPrice = $totalPrice;
        return $this;
    }


    public function getInvoice(): ?Invoice
    {
        return $this->invoice;
    }
}
```

and this is my invoice entity:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Bundle\Entity;

#[ORM\Entity(repositoryClass: InvoiceRepository::class)]
#[ORM\Table(name: '`invoice`')]
#[ApiResource(
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read:Invoice']],
    denormalizationContext: ['groups' => ['write:Invoice', 'read:Invoice']],
    collectionOperations: [
        'get',
        'post'
    ],
    itemOperations: [
        'get',
        'put',
        'delete'
    ],
)]
class Invoice
{
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy: 'AUTO')]
    #[ORM\Column(type: Types::INTEGER)]
    #[Groups(['read:Invoice'])]
    private ?int $id;

    #[MaxDepth(100)]
    #[ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity: InvoiceLineItems::class, mappedBy: 'invoice', cascade: ['persist', 'remove'])]
    #[Groups(['read:Invoice', 'write:Invoice'])]
    private $invoiceLineItems;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->invoiceLineItems = new ArrayCollection();
    }


    public function getId(): ?int
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

 
    public function getInvoiceLineItems(): ?Collection
    {
        return $this->invoiceLineItems;
    }

    public function setInvoiceLineItems(Collection $invoiceLineItems): self
    {
        foreach ($invoiceLineItems as $lineItemData) {
            $lineItem = new InvoiceLineItem();
            $lineItem->setDescription($lineItemData['description'] ?? null);
            $lineItem->setSubDescription($lineItemData['subDescription'] ?? null);
            $lineItem->setPrice($lineItemData['price'] ?? null);
            $lineItem->setVATPercentage($lineItemData['vatPercentage'] ?? null);
            $lineItem->setVat($lineItemData['vat'] ?? null);
            $lineItem->setTotalPrice($lineItemData['totalPrice'] ?? null);
            $lineItem->setInvoice($this);
            $this->invoiceLineItems->add($lineItem);
        }

        return $this;
    }

}
```

I have tried explicitly setting the argument type to array and ArrayCollection but it still throws the error

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: If `$invoiceLineItems` is an array of entities, why you use it as array `$lineItemData['description']` instead of `$lineItemData->getDescription()`